# Error code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' trying to deploy bot on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, twitter, bots

I'm trying to deploy my Twitter Bot on Heroku, but I can't.

I have configured the Twitter keys in the Heroku Vars, the package.json is okay... I have investigated in Google, but I can not find the solution. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone give me a hand?

The **error** is this:

```
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326219+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326219+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326219+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326220+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326221+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326221+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 
'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326221+00:00 app[worker.1]:   
requireStack: [ '/app/bot.js' ]
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326222+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
2020-09-04T09:05:15.389873+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process 
exited with status 1
2020-09-04T09:05:15.422459+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State 
changed from up to crashed
```

**Package.json**:

```
{
"name": "addicteddev",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Addicted Dev - Twitter Bot",
"main": "bot.js",
"dependencies": {
"twit": "^2.2.11",
"twitter": "^1.7.1"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url":
"git+https://github.com/pablohs1986/
 addictedDEV_TwitterBot.git"
 },
"keywords": [
"bot",
"twitter",
"javascript",
"nodejs",
"dev"
],
"author": "Pablo Herrero",
"license": "MIT",
"bugs": {
"url": 
"https://github.com/pablohs1986/
 addictedDEV_TwitterBot/issues"
},
"homepage": 
"https://github.com/pablohs1986/
 addictedDEV_TwitterBot#readme"
}
```

**Bot.js**:

```
// Setup
    console.log('The bot is starting');

    var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./config/config.js');
var T = new Twit(config);

var addDevStatuses = [
    "asdasdasdsa"
];

let hashtags = [
    '#java', '#Java', '#js', '#javascript', '#JavaScript', '#python', '#Python', '#nodejs', '#nodeJS', '#100DaysOfCode', '#100daysofcode', '#100DOC', '#100doc', '#stackoverflow', 
    '#StackOverFlow', '#angular', '#Angular', '#VSCode', '#vscode', '#Netbeans', '#netbeans', '#Oracle', '#oracle', '#dev', '#Dev', '#developer', '#Developer', '#Development', '#development', '#sql', '#SQL'
]

// function randomStatus(){
//     return status = addDevStatuses[Math.floor(Math.random()*addDevStatuses.length)];
// }

function returnRandomElementFromArray(array){
    return status = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}

function onlyUniqueTweets(value, index, self){
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// Post every 2 hours
function tweetIt(text){
    var params = {
        status: text
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("Shit!!");
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("It worked! Tweeting!!");
        }
    })
}

tweetIt(returnRandomElementFromArray(addDevStatuses));
setInterval(tweetIt, 1000*60*120, returnRandomElementFromArray(addDevStatuses));

// Retweet hashtags
function retweetHashtags(hashtag){
    var params = {
        q: hashtag + ' ',
        result_type: 'mixed',
        count: '5'
    }

    T.get('search/tweets', params, function(err_search, data_search, response_search){
        let tweets = data_search.statuses;
       
        if(err_search){
            console.log("Shit searching!!");
            console.log(err_search);
        }else{
            var tweetIDList = [];
            
            for(let tweet of tweets){
                if(tweet.text.startsWith("RT @")){
                    if(tweet.retweeted_status){
                        tweetIDList.push(tweet.retweeted_status.id_str);
                    }else{
                        tweetIDList.push(tweet.id_str);
                    }
                }else{
                    tweetIDList.push(tweet.id_str);
                }
            }

            tweetIDList = tweetIDList.filter(onlyUniqueTweets);

            console.log("TweetIDList = \n" + tweetIDList);

            for (let tweetID of tweetIDList) {
                T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', {id : tweetID}, function(err_rt, data_rt, response_rt){
                    if(!err_rt){
                        console.log("\n\nRetweeted! ID - " + tweetID);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("\nShit retweeting!! Duplication maybe... " + tweetID + "| HASHTAG - " + hashtag);
                        console.log("Error: " + err_rt);
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log("It worked! Hashtags retweeted!!!");
        }
    })
}

retweetHashtags(returnRandomElementFromArray(hashtags));
setInterval(retweetHashtags, 1000*60*10, returnRandomElementFromArray(hashtags));
```

Comment: You would need to show more details like the code to get more help on this

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found it, so **I'll try to answer the question**:

It was finally **a routing problem**. When deploying the bot on Heroku, the program was not getting access to the config.js file or bot.js.

Config.js did not want to make it public because it had the Twitter keys in it. Finally I have made it public, but referring to the Config.env file, which is where the Twitter keys are actually read (stored in the Heroku Vars), which I access through the [dotenv] module (https: // www .npmjs.com / package / dotenv) as I show below:

**Config.js**:

```
const path = require('path')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
require('dotenv').config();
// Load config
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })

module.exports = {
    consumer_key : process.env.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret : process.env.API_SECRET_KEY,
    access_token : process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret : process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
};
```

Once the push is done, it works perfectly.

Hope this is helpful if something similar happens to someone in the future :)